# C++ Template Call member function if matching type else throw exception?

Tags: c++, class, templates, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Consider the following class:

```
class Example {
    const void * pValue;
    (Example& (*SIndex(const void *,char *)));
    (Example& (*NIndex(const void *,unsigned long long *)));

    template<class T,typename I> static  Example & Index(const T* value,I index)
    { return Example(value->operator[](index)); }

public:
    template<class T> Example(const T& value) {
        pValue = &value;
        SIndex = (Example& (*(const void *,char *)))Index<T,char *>;
        NIndex = (Example& (*(const void *,unsigned long long)))Index<T,unsigned long long>;
    };
    Example& operator[](char * index) { return SIndex(pValue,index); };
    Example& operator[](unsigned long long) { return NIndex(pValue,index); };
}
```

I wish to use SFINAE (Substitution failure is not an error) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), to alter _Index such that if there is no matching operator for the class it will throw an exception rather than return a new Example object. i.e. for `_Index<T,char *>` will match `operator[](char *)` or `operator[](std::string&)` as `std::string` can be constructed from `char *` while `_Index<T,unsigned long long>` will match any numerical type, as `unsigned long long` can be converted.

I have only just come across SFINAE while looking for solutions to this problem it clear the solution would lay in this, however I'm not sure how to implement it.

Example (As Requested):
This will compile, currently the output is the pointer value no content, but that is fixable, Also I disabled the String Index Option as that causes a compiler error with out working SFINAE. Note it real world application obj1 and obj2 may be different types i.e.
vector and map however will produce errors until SFINAE is added to the code to produce exceptions instead. Also the "index path" to open will be detriment at run time NOT compile time.
Note: I'm working on extending this code https://github.com/vitaut/format to allow ids of the type {0[4][first]} or {1[error]} etc. Since not all object support these methods the object not supporting it should produce an runtime exception when the format string asks for it, also must not produce compiler errors, as any type used as an argument will be passed in to the Arg class, Example, just shows the part of the More complex Arg class I need to modify to get this working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Example {
    void * pValue;
    /*Example& (*SIndex)(void*,const char *);*/
    Example& (*NIndex)(void*,unsigned int);
    template<class T,typename I> static Example& Index(T* obj,I index) {
        return *(new Example((*obj)[index])); }
public:
    Example(char value) { pValue = &value; }
    template<class T> Example(T& value) {
        pValue = &value;
        /*SIndex = (Example& (*)(void*,const char *))Index<T,const char *>;*/
        NIndex = (Example& (*)(void*,unsigned int))Index<T,unsigned int>;
    }
    /*Example& operator[](const char * index) { return SIndex(pValue,index); }*/
    Example& operator[](unsigned int index) { return NIndex(pValue,index); }
    void * Get() { return pValue; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Example> Objs;
    vector<string> obj1;
    vector<string> obj2;
    obj1.push_back("Hello ");
    obj1.push_back("World");
    obj2.push_back("Olleh ");
    obj2.push_back("Dlorw");
    Objs.push_back(Example(obj1));
    Objs.push_back(Example(obj2));
    cout << (string *)(Objs[0][0].Get()) << endl;
    cout << (string *)(Objs[1][1].Get()) << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Example 2 (with Simple's SFINALE code) v2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T, typename I>
decltype(void((*declval<T>())[declval<I>()]), true_type())
has_subscript_test(int);

template<typename, typename>
false_type
has_subscript_test(...);

template<typename T, typename I>
struct has_subscript : decltype(has_subscript_test<T, I>(0))
{
};

class Example {
    void * pValue;
    Example& (*SIndex)(void*,const char *);
    Example& (*NIndex)(void*,unsigned int);
    template<class T,typename I> static
    typename enable_if<has_subscript<T, I>::value, Example&>::type
    Index(T* obj,I index) { return *(new Example((*obj)[index])); }
    template<class T,typename I> static
    typename enable_if<!has_subscript<T, I>::value, Example&>::type
    Index(T* obj,I index) { throw "Invalid Index Type"; }
public:
    //Example(char value) { pValue = &value; }
    template<class T> Example(T& value) {
        pValue = &value;
        SIndex = (Example& (*)(void*,const char *))Index<T,const char *>;
        NIndex = (Example& (*)(void*,unsigned int))Index<T,unsigned int>;
    }
    Example& operator[](const char* index) { return SIndex(pVale,index); }
    Example& operator[](unsigned int index) { return NIndex(pValue,index); }
    void * Get() { return pValue; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Example> Objs;
    vector<string> obj1;
    map<string,string> obj2;
    obj1.push_back("Hello ");
    obj1.push_back("World");
    obj2["A"] = "Olleh ";
    obj2["B"] = "Dlorw";
    Objs.push_back(Example(obj1));
    Objs.push_back(Example(obj2));
    cout << (string *)(Objs[0][(unsigned int)0].Get()) << endl;
    cout << (string *)(Objs[1][(const char *)"B"].Get()) << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

compiler errors:
Looks like only the first 2 are important the rest are a side effect of those 2.

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -std=c++11 -g     -c C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp -o ../obj/Debug/main.o
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp: In instantiation of â€˜static typename std::enable_if<has_subscript<T, I>::value, Example&>::type Example::Index(T*, I) [with T = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >; I = const char*; typename std::enable_if<has_subscript<T, I>::value, Example&>::type = Example&]â€™:
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:37:9:   required from â€˜Example::Example(T&) [with T = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >]â€™
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:54:32:   required from here
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:29:64: error: invalid conversion from â€˜const char*â€™ to â€˜std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::size_type {aka unsigned int}â€™ [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/vector:65:0,
                 from C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:3:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:750:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of â€˜std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = std::basic_string<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = std::basic_string<char>&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]â€™ [-fpermissive]
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp: In instantiation of â€˜static typename std::enable_if<has_subscript<T, I>::value, Example&>::type Example::Index(T*, I) [with T = std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >; I = unsigned int; typename std::enable_if<has_subscript<T, I>::value, Example&>::type = Example&]â€™:
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:38:9:   required from â€˜Example::Example(T&) [with T = std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >]â€™
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:55:32:   required from here
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:29:64: error: invalid user-defined conversion from â€˜unsigned intâ€™ to â€˜std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::key_type&& {aka std::basic_string<char>&&}â€™ [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/string:54:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/ios:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/iostream:40,
                 from C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:487:7: note: candidate is: std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:487:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from â€˜unsigned intâ€™ to â€˜const char*â€™
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:29:64: error: invalid conversion from â€˜unsigned intâ€™ to â€˜const char*â€™ [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/string:54:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/ios:43,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/iostream:40,
                 from C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:487:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of â€˜std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]â€™ [-fpermissive]
C:/SourceCode/Test/main.cpp:29:64: error: conversion to non-const reference type â€˜std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >::key_type&& {aka class std::basic_string<char>&&}â€™ from rvalue of type â€˜std::basic_string<char>â€™ [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Note: your code is technically illegal. Names starting with an underscore followed by a capital letter (as well as those containing two consecutive underscores) are reserved for the implementation (compiler & standard library). They must not be used in user code.

Comment: If you can detect it at compile time, why do you want to compile then throw a runtime exception?  There are situations where that is valid, but are you in them?

Comment: Yes I'm extending a string formatting library, to provide subscript of the arguments, I the object doesn't support it it should throw an exception, not crash, but the function must exist for any type passed to the string formatter, so its invalid calling the function represents an exception/runtime error

Comment: I'm with Yakk: is there a reason why this shouldn't be a compile-time error? Seems to me that passing a float to [] is a syntax error, not a semantics error. That is, why isn't code that passes a float considered wrong code, rather than invalid runtime state?

Comment: As noted below, the above code does not compile.  So that we know what you want, can you write a http://sscce.org that compiles and works for the cases where you do not want it to throw?  I will assume that for any type your http://sscce.org does notcompile on, you want it to throw...

Comment: @leewangzhong you can pass any type to the subscript operator (which is what im looking at) as long as an overload exists for that type. And its a runtime error as my code is determining index and index type at runtime, the exception isn't that the code is wrong, its that the string passed to the code is requesting an invalid index be loaded.

Comment: `return *(new Example((*obj)[index]));` No no no no no no.

Comment: @simple I know its bad code and cause memory leaks, but its easy to write for test code where I don't care about memory leaks and removes temporary problems.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
template<typename T, typename I>
decltype(void((*std::declval<T>())[std::declval<I>()]), std::true_type())
has_subscript_test(int);

template<typename, typename>
std::false_type
has_subscript_test(...);

template<typename T, typename I>
struct has_subscript : decltype(has_subscript_test<T, I>(0))
{
};

class Example {
    const void * pValue;
    (Example& (*SIndex(const void *,char *)));
    (Example& (*NIndex(const void *,unsigned long long *)));

    template<class T, typename I> static
    typename std::enable_if<has_subscript<T, I>::value, Example&>::type
    _Index(const T* value,I index) { return Example((*value)[index]); }

    template<class T, typename I> static
    typename std::enable_if<!has_subscript<T, I>::value, Example&>::type
    _Index(const T*,I) { throw "uh-oh!"; }
public:
    template<class T> Example(const T& value) {
        pValue = &value;
        SIndex = (Example& (*(const void *,char *)))_Index<T,char *>;
        NIndex = (Example& (*(const void *,unsigned long long)))_Index<T,unsigned long long>;
    };
    Example& operator[](char * index) { return SIndex(this,index); };
    Example& operator[](unsigned long long) { return NIndex(this,index); };
};
```

I've done the SFINAE bit but there are other problems with your code. `_Index` is not allowed as a name, you're returning a temporary by reference and you're trying to cast a member pointer to a function pointer (even with a different function type!)

Comment: Wouldn't that only work if T[index] returned an object of Example? the example object should be created by the fact that the returned value is used to construct a new Example object. Say T is std::map<std::string,X> where X is some other class, SIndex should do Example(X), while NIndex should throw an error. would this code still work then?

Comment: I literally just added the SFINAE to your already existant code which I assumed did what you wanted. It should work the same now as it did before, just with the added throwing an exception. Note there are errors in your code that I pointed out.

Comment: Oh yes _Index is mean to be static, the code is just an example I quickly wrote up to demonstrate what I'm trying to do, My actual code is more complex.

Comment: @glenflet even after `_Index` is made `static`, you're still casting to the wrong function type (I don't understand why you need `SIndex` or `NIndex`...) and then calling it through that incorrect function pointer. A big no-no.

Comment: I know the pointer type is wrong, but the CPU doesn't care only the compiler the pointer is just a memory location basically I tell the compiler the pointer is actually a void * then later I tell it is is actually a T* since I know the pointer actually points to a T*, note the class store whatever object is passed to the constructor as a void pointer, and that's what I need the SIndex and NIndex for they will point to a function generated from the template for the specific class. My code actually use an array of these to represent a array of arbarty objects.

Comment: @glenflet I don't see where you cast back the function pointer from `Example& (*)(const void *,char *)` to `Example& (*)(const T *,char *)` which *is* required or else you get undefined behaviour. You are also trying to deference a `void*` which is obviously not allowed.

Comment: This is the generic idiomatic way of building SFINAE, start by building the metafunction, then use that metafunction inside a `enable_if`. Yet, this could be done with far less code by merging the metafunction with the use.

Comment: @glenflet: You might want to reconsider the approach and use something like `boost::any` or a variant type. The current approach is not type safe. You loose the information about the type and depend on your user tracking that information for you, and you have no way of validating the user's assumption. This is *very error prone* and you will mess the types sooner or later causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @simple don't need to cast back to ```Example& (*)(const T *,char *)``` as thats still the type the function was compiled as the and T* and void* are both a number of the same size witch is the address of the object of type T, so I pass in a void*, but the functions code interprets that value as a T* so there is a second cast there its just hidden.

Comment: @dribeas The actual code is just an object container used by a framework, see https://github.com/vitaut/format Arg class, which I'm extending, the only place the type is need is in function pointers set up in the constructor these functions have implicit knowledge of the types they expect to be passed hence there is an implicit cast back to correct type by calling them even though I only store a void *, so there should never be a problem with the lack of type information.

Comment: @simple I added your SFINALE to my example this produces errors are there any required headers??

Comment: @glenflet it doesn't matter that calling the function through a `Example& (*)(void const*, char*)` "works"; it's undefined behaviour by the standard so you shouldn't do it. Assuming the errors I pointed out have been fixed then you'll need to include `<type_traits>` and `<utility>`.

Comment: @Simple Include those and it gives me the following error ```error: expected initializer before & token``` Note Index is declared static in my code but I don't see how that would cause such an error. The error occurs on the line the function is on not the line your code is on. As for undefined behavior so you think I should declare the the function void*, and change ```(*value)[index]``` to ```(*(T*)value)[index]``` as the machine code should be identical, so I don't really see the difference except in terms of neatness.

Comment: @glenflet Without a line number & up-to-date code I don't know what you expect me to do. :P

Comment: @Simple I've added the full code + g++ output to the bottom of my question.

Comment: @glenflet Ok, I looked at it. I made a typo. Sorry. On lines 29 and 32 you need to move the `static` after the `template<...>` and remove the `Example&` (so `_Index` starts the line).

Comment: @simple I made those modification however it still doesn't compile, I update my question with the new code and errors, it appear the compiler is trying to use the subscript operator when it should be throwing the exception.

Comment: @Simple I got the code to show the value of ```has_subscript<T, I>::value``` and it was always ```true``` however by changing ```decltype(void((*std::declval<T>())[std::declval<I>()]), std::true_type())``` to ```decltype(declval<T>()[declval<I>()], true_type())``` I go that to output the correct value, however no my compiler outputs errors setting [NS]Index to Index<T,I> it gives ```error: insufficient contextual information to determine type```, code ```SIndex = (Example& (*)(const void*,const char *))Index<T,const char *>``` any idea what could cause this or how to get around?

Comment: @Simple Also if you update your answer so it has the correct decltype I'll accept your answer since it dose what my question asked.

Comment: @Simple I have it working now changed it to ```template<class T,typename I,typename enable_if<has_subscript<T, I>::value, int>::type = 0> static inline
Example& Index(T* obj,I index) { return *(new Example((*obj)[index])); }``` the enable_if must prevent the compiler resolving the type correctly or something.